# "Failed building wheel for pandas" when pip installing in JupyterNotebook

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to the Synpase package

> https://python-docs.synapse.org/build/html/index.html

in Jupyter notebook file using

`!pip install synapseclient[pandas,pysftp]`

, but whenever I try and run this it gives me the error "Failed building wheel for pandas". What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Try running `!pip install -vvv synapseclient[pandas,pysftp]` and add the output to the question.